# Two inner loops optimization in openmp

Tags: gcc, parallel-processing, openmp

I spend some time playing around with openmp on nested loops, however, I can't make it work in case there are 2+ inner loops. Is it possible to use openmp pragmas on 2+ inner cycles (without rewriting it back to one with conditional statement)?

```
for (i = 1; i <= n; i++)
{
  for (w = 0; w <= in[i][W]; w++)
    a[i][w] = a[i-1][w];

  for (w = in[i][W]+1; w <= wc; w++)
    a[i][w] = max(a[i-1][w], in[i][V] + a[i-1][w-in[i][W]]);
}
```

Comment: What is `V`, `W` and `in`?

Comment: Both `V` and `W` are constants; `W = 0`, `V = 1`, so clearly array is of `2(n+1)` size

Answer (score -1):

What are you trying to achieve? Why do you wwant the inner loops split?

What makes you think it has any merit to parallellize the inner loop?

What is the problem parallellizing them anyways?

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4b2172f5ddadba20)</kbd>**

```
#include <omp.h>

int main()
{
    for (int i=0; i <100; ++i)
    {
        int m = 5000;

#pragma omp parallel for 
        for (int j=0; j<m; ++j)
        {
        }

#pragma omp parallel for 
        for (int j=m; j<2*m; ++j)
        {
        }

    }
}
```

If you just want to do manual chunking, look at: [schedule clauses](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenMP#Scheduling_clauses)

If you want explicit control over which team threads run what section:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ed697ff2a4615bda)</kbd>**

```
#include <omp.h>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    int id = 0;
#pragma omp parallel
    {
        int m = 5000;
        std::cout << "parallel section #" << ++id << "\n";

        {
#pragma omp single
            std::cout << "first single section\n";
            for (int j=0; j<m; ++j)
            {
            }
        }

        {
#pragma omp single
            std::cout << "second single section\n";
            for (int j=m; j<2*m; ++j)
            {
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Output:

```
parallel section #1
parallel section #2
first single section
parallel section #3
parallel section #4
second single section
```